# SORT, UNIQUE, SLICE(LIMIT) - PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, unique, slice

I got this data in an array:

```
 name | points
---------------
joe   |   20
mike  |   18
tim   |   19
tina  |   22
mike  |   20
joe   |   21
tim   |   19
mike  |   21
tim   |   19
tina  |   20
```

I want to put out the TOP 3 of points, so that there are only 3 lines and all the names behind it - of course every name only once, even if a name got the same points multiple times.

```
TOP 3

 points |      names
---------------------------
   18   |  mike
   19   |  tim
   20   |  joe, mike, tina
```

Anyone?

Comment: Did you try anything? Looking at the manual page for each of those functions maybe?

Comment: Sure, but I was not able to combine all these things together!

Comment: [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) might help

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT is SQL, I need PHP